# iPad App Developement with PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, cordova

I have developed an application for iPhone using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com).

Can i reuse it for iPad? If not, what changes are required?

Comment: Yes U can use same code but have to use different XIB

Comment: Just copy paste that for iPad application n use different XIB

Answer (score 0):

you can reuse your project and all of your code 
all what you must replace its your css files

(phonegap wiki)
1) edit the Project Settings (Project > Edit Project Settings) menu option
2)In the 'Build' tab, scroll down to the 'Deployment' section
3)Change the Targeted Device Family to 'iPad'